# Optimisation with Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, soft-question, nonlinear-optimization, simplex

This is a soft-question. Most of the value the links I see only address the optimization with equality constraints and get a solution via some analytical method such as Lagrange Multipliers. Say if I want to maximize an objective function  $f (\mathbf{\theta})$ (note:$\theta$ is an n-dimensional vector) that is not necessarily convex with the equality constraints such that a subset of the parameter values sum to 1 and that these parameters are overlapping in each constraint. For example, $\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3=1$, $\theta_2+\theta_3+\theta_4=1$, $\theta_4+\theta_5+\theta_6=1$, $\dots$. Suppose that there are $m$ of these equations/equality constraints. My questions are

- Is there any suggestion of computational methods that deal with the optimization when $m$ is a large number? Any links or references will be appreciated
- Generally speaking, do I face any complexity issues when performing the optimization. From your experience, how large can $m$ become before it becomes computationally infeasible to optimize?
- Will I be able to achieve a global maximum?

I understand that a lot of this depends on the objective function $f(\mathbf{\theta})$. I do not know what the term is to classify $f(\mathbf{\theta} )$  but the objective function is of the shape:

$$f(\mathbf{\theta})=\frac{(\sum^n_{i=1}w_i \theta_i)^2}{n\sum_{i=1}^n(w_i\theta_i)^2}$$

where $\mathbf{w}$ are just constants

Comment: Interesting problem. What about the $w_i$'s ? Are they all $\geq 0$ ? How large can be $m$ compared to $n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thx for the reply. $w_i$'s are all positive or zero. $m$ can be a lot larger than $n$, in my belief. $n$ is the number of vertices on a graph and $m$ is the number of branches in all trees(not all trees but known ones) of that graph.

Comment: Could you provide me a *small* problem ? You can find my e-mail address in my profile.